# How to apply styles to child elements in polymer

Tags: polymer, nuxeo

Hi I want to Apply the styles to the child elements in the polymer.

i have 2 dom modules in same file i want to apply style from parent to the dom

Here is my 2 dom's

DOM1:

```
<dom-module id="nuxeo-document-blob" assetpath="nuxeo-document-blob/"><template>

<style include="nuxeo-styles">
  :host {
    display: block;
  }
  .row {
    @apply --layout-horizontal;
    @apply --layout-center;
  }

  .row .info {
    @apply --layout-vertical;
    @apply --layout-flex;
  }

  .row .actions {
    @apply --layout-horizontal;
    @apply --layout-center;
  }

  .detail {
    opacity: .5;
  }

  .actions ::content paper-icon-button {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
  }
</style>

<nuxeo-connection user="{{user}}"></nuxeo-connection>

<template is="dom-if" if="[[blob]]">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="info">
      <div><a href="[[blob.data]]">[[blob.name]]</a></div>
      <div class="detail">[[formatSize(blob.length)]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions" id="test_action">
      <nuxeo-slot slot="BLOB_ACTIONS" model="[[actionContext]]"></nuxeo-slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my dom2:

```
<dom-module id="nuxeo-document-viewer" assetpath="nuxeo-document-viewer/"<template>
<style include="nuxeo-styles">
  nuxeo-dropzone {
    height: calc(80vh - 100px);
    display: block;
  }

  nuxeo-document-preview {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(80vh - 100px);
    display: block;
  }

  nuxeo-document-blob {
    margin-top: 8px;
   /* display:none !important; */
  } 
  .testblob ::nuxeo-document-blob > .row .actions  {
    display:none !important;
  }
</style>

<nuxeo-dropzone document="{{document}}" hidden$="[[document.properties.file:content.data]]" update-document=""></nuxeo-dropzone>
<nuxeo-document-preview document="[[document]]" hidden$="[[!document.properties.file:content.data]]"></nuxeo-document-preview>
<div class="testblob">
<nuxeo-document-blob document="[[document]]" hidden$="[[!document.properties.file:content.data]]"></nuxeo-document-blob>
</div>
```

Here the dom2 is parent and dom1 is child i want to apply the styles to child inner elements class actions.

Is there any way to apply this in polymer.

help me solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .testblob nuxeo-document-blob ::content .row .actions  {
    display:none !important;
  }
```

Try `::slot` too instead of `::content`.

Comment: @RicKarsEliimaa i have tried the both it is still not applying